# How do I handle parameterisation for custom user filters?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I'm managing a MS Access application where one of the features is a list of projects with about 20 attribute columns. Most of these columns can be filtered individually. Naturally, this has led to pretty extreme parameterisation problems, with a flood of single use queries going into the plan cache. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM tblProject WHERE LeadEngineerID = 4 AND CompanyID = 6
SELECT * FROM tblProject WHERE Address = '123 Test Avenue' AND StateID = 2
```

And so on. Checking the creation date of plans in my cache, I find that the majority were created in the last day.

Is there a way to specify that these queries shouldn't go into the cache? These queries could return any number of results, so trying to parameterise them would run headfirst into sniffing problems. I tried optimising for ad-hoc, but I don't think that did what I expected, as the problem has persisted.

Comment: What is the actual problem you're currently facing with having each instance of these queries in your plan cache? How do you know you'd run into parameter sniffing problems if you did parameterize them?

Comment: Keep in mind that I'm still learning my way around, but to the best of my knowledge: My server is unable to remember plans it can actually reuse because there are way too many different plans being sent in. I'm fairly sure I will get parameter sniffing - isn't this exactly the kind of situation that causes it? For example, we've done hundreds of projects with some companies, and just one or two with others. The overall symptom is that there is significant lag somewhere in the database, which I'm trying to locate. This is my best guess of where to start.

Comment: Just for reference I'm getting information from Brent Ozar's blog, specifically this page.

https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/07/tsql2sday-how-much-plan-cache-history-do-you-have/

Comment: "*The overall symptom is that there is significant lag somewhere in the database*" - If your plan cache is full, then all that means is other queries who can't store their plan in the cache will need to recompile a new plan each time they run. Ideally this should take no more than a few milliseconds to do, and not be a significant problem per se. If a query is taking seconds or longer to build a plan, then it's likely a sign of a poorly written or overly complex query, meaning the fix is tuning how that query is written. Otherwise, if you have a specifically slow process, you should get the...

Comment: ...actual execution plans of the queries involved in that process to pinpoint the root issue. But it sounds based on your description unlikely to be your plan cache, that's the issue.

Comment: "*I'm fairly sure I will get parameter sniffing - isn't this exactly the kind of situation that causes it?*" - Parameter Sniffing is a good thing, it prevents redundant plans in the plan cache and helps minimize plan recompilation. Parameter Sniffing problems are an issue when there's a large cardinality of rows difference between two values of the same parameter that's used in a predicate of a query. E.g. if `LeadEngineerID = 4` results in a cardinality of 1 row but `LeadEngineerID = 7` resulted in 1 million. You haven't provided any information to indicate that you'd have this problem yet.

Comment: Ok, let's set aside parameter sniffing for now - I'll admit my understanding of it is probably flawed. Let me rephrase why I'm trying to get rid of parameterisation issues first, instead of looking for the slowest queries. It's from the same article I linked above. Quote - "Looking at the top 10 plans in the cache doesn’t do me much good if the developers aren't parameterising their queries". Indeed, when I run sp_BlitzCache, the first warning that comes up states my plan cache is very unstable, with 88% of plans created in the last 24 hours.

Comment: Am I going about this the wrong way as well? My interpretation is that I need to address parameterisation issues first before I can do anything else productive.

Comment: "*Am I going about this the wrong way as well? My interpretation is that I need to address parameterisation issues first before I can do anything else productive.*" - Yea, I think you are since again having a full plan cache isn't really your root issue to a significant performance problem. I find the "*% of plans created*" a little bit insignificant and have seen it say upwards of 95% of plans created in the last hour, but it didn't matter as far as the database performance was concerned - performance was fine. You can solve your significant performance issues by directly facing them instead.

Comment: "*Looking at the top 10 plans in the cache doesn’t do me much good if the developers aren't parameterising their queries*" - This is only true if you're phishing for things that have problems by the top queries in the plan cache, assumptively when you aren't already aware of existing issues. And even then it's not always true, as the top queries might continue to always re-appear at the top, even when not properly parameterized - the fix for them can be constant, regardless. You seem to already be aware of performance issues with a specific query, process, or workflow, so again, you should...

Comment: ...be looking at **that** specific slow *thing* and trying to understand why it's slow (typically by analyzing the execution plan(s) of the underlying queries). It's not going to be because your plan cache is full with newly created plans in the last 24 hours, and fixing that issue won't fix your performance issues.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your advice. I don't actually know the exact thing which is slow, but I'll ask my users for more specifics.